# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL timed out

Tags: c#, azure-devops, appium, azure-pipelines, appium-ios

I am trying to automate UI Tests with Appium with the C# driver for iOS. The UI Tests run successfully on the localhost, however they fail when running on the Azure Pipelines host Mac agent.

I can see from the nearly 15MB log file that Appium is running, and seems to be creating the session as I have an abundance of useless logs from the iOS Simulator. I also know from some unit tests that I can spin up appium on the CI build agent and successfully call the status endpoint.

However all of my UI Tests fail with the error:

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds.

**Note** I also tried to increase the timeout here in case for some reason the default 60 seconds wasn't enough...

Has someone run into this before? Is there perhaps a dependency that could be missing that would resolve the issue? Below are the capabilities sent to Appium from the logs.

```json
{
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "deviceName": "iPhone 12 Pro",
    "app": "/Users/runner/work/1/UITests/bin/device/TestApp.iOS.app",
    "platformName": "iOS",
    "platformVersion": "14.4",
    "automationName": "XCUITest",
    "autoAcceptAlerts": true,
    "launchTimeout": 60000,
    "appium:screenshotQuality": 2,
    "appium:showIOSLog": true
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "platformName": "iOS",
        "appium:screenshotQuality": 2,
        "appium:showIOSLog": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can see the full solution at https://github.com/dansiegel/xappium.uitest

EDIT:

See the output from the trx file generated by dotnet test.

```
<UnitTestResult executionId="3e2455a4-2c2f-471f-899e-ebd2818e9409" testId="84168d84-ecc4-f6b8-035c-a175da356cd5" testName="TestApp.UITests.AppTests.LogsIntoMainPage" computerName="Mac-1615530590015" duration="00:00:00.0010000" startTime="2021-03-12T06:44:07.9592900+00:00" endTime="2021-03-12T06:44:07.9592970+00:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Failed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" relativeResultsDirectory="3e2455a4-2c2f-471f-899e-ebd2818e9409">
  <Output>
    <ErrorInfo>
      <Message>OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session timed out after 90 seconds.
---- System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out.</Message>
      <StackTrace>   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service.AppiumCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities appiumOptions)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities appiumOptions, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.iOS.IOSDriver`1..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, DriverOptions driverOptions, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at Xappium.UITest.Platforms.iOSXappiumTestEngine.CreateDriver(AppiumOptions options, UITestConfiguration config) in /_/src/Xappium.UITest/Platforms/iOSXappiumTestEngine.cs:line 34
at Xappium.UITest.Platforms.XappiumTestEngineBase`2.SetupDriver() in /_/src/Xappium.UITest/Platforms/XappiumTestEngineBase.cs:line 38
at Xappium.UITest.Platforms.XappiumTestEngineBase`2..ctor(UITestConfiguration config) in /_/src/Xappium.UITest/Platforms/XappiumTestEngineBase.cs:line 31
at Xappium.UITest.Platforms.iOSXappiumTestEngine..ctor(UITestConfiguration config) in /_/src/Xappium.UITest/Platforms/iOSXappiumTestEngine.cs:line 16
at Xappium.UITest.AppManager.StartApp(UITestConfiguration testConfig) in /_/src/Xappium.UITest/AppManager.cs:line 59
at Xappium.UITest.AppManager.StartApp() in /_/src/Xappium.UITest/AppManager.cs:line 30
at TestApp.UITests.AppTests..ctor() in /_/sample/TestApp.UITests/AppTests.cs:line 15
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)</StackTrace>
    </ErrorInfo>
  </Output>
</UnitTestResult>
```

Comment: How's your pipeline like?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT can you expand on your question? The repo and pipeline are all open source

Comment: Sorry I missed that open source. Could you set variable `system.debug` to `true` to check whether you could get more information in the log?

Comment: Please look at the Run Tests stage for build [1906](https://dev.azure.com/dansiegel/Xappium.UITest/_build/results?buildId=1906&view=results)

Comment: There is no time out issue in the log, where did you get time out issue?

Comment: The full logs are in the iOS-uitest artifact. You can see the error in the trx. I've added the stdout from vstest to the console output... you can see it [here](https://dev.azure.com/dansiegel/Xappium.UITest/_build/results?buildId=1914&view=logs&j=a2de5c4d-e0b8-5eb1-ef75-7b8154f8c2e3&t=48048ef5-7f01-51a7-8902-828abf940eda)... or see all of the logs in the artifact.

Comment: Could you try to set all timeout capability type and increase them to see how's the result? https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/.